# how to add existing subnetwork for gke cluster using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I am adding vpc, subnet and gke cluster referring to that vpc and subnet. However, vpc and subnet are getting created but while creating gke cluster it is throwing error that

```
Create cluster cannot be created with existing subnetwork.
```

I have added the below script which is creating VPC, subnetwork and gke cluster. Please see the terraform script below

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = "gkecredential"
  project     = "abc"
  region      = "us-central1"
}

resource "google_compute_network" "vpc" {
  name                    = "test"
  auto_create_subnetworks = "false"
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "gkesubnet" {
  name          = "testgkesubnet"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.105.0.0/24"
  network       = "${google_compute_network.vpc.self_link}"
  region        = "us-central1"

  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = "container-range-1"
    ip_cidr_range = "10.75.0.0/20"
  }

  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = "service-range-1"
    ip_cidr_range = "10.8.0.0/14"
  }
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "gcp_kubernetes" {
  name               = "gkecluster"
  zone               = "us-west1-a"
  initial_node_count = "1"
  network            = "${google_compute_network.vpc.self_link}"
  subnetwork         = "${google_compute_network.gkesubnet.self_link}"

  additional_zones = [
    "us-west1-b",
    "us-west1-c",
  ]

  private_cluster_config {
    enable_private_endpoint = false
    enable_private_nodes    = true
    master_ipv4_cidr_block  = "172.16.0.0/28"
  }

  master_auth {
    username = "abc"
    password = "abc"
  }

  master_authorized_networks_config {
    cidr_blocks = [
      {
        cidr_block   = "10.102.0.0/24"
        display_name = "Office"
      },
    ]
  }

  ip_allocation_policy {
    create_subnetwork = true
  }

  node_config {
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
    ]

    labels {
      this-is-for = "dev-cluster"
    }

    tags = ["dev", "work"]
  }
}
```

Comment: What would the equivalent gcloud commands be for performing this task manually in a script?

Comment: @Sarabjeet Singh , did you tried to create first the vpc and subnet and after confirmed that the vpc is done create the cluster? I'm prety sure you can not do all together.

Comment: The resource reference you are using for the subnet is refering a `google_compute_network` resource instead of a `google_compute_subnetwork` resource. Is that a typo in the code you're attempting to apply or in the code you posted here?

Comment: hey guys it worked for me. I used the below github link   https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/1382

Comment: @Sarabjeet Singh Can you please post your solution as an answer so it can get upvoted and help other members? Thanks.

Comment: ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name = "abc-pod"
 services_secondary_range_name = "abc-services"
  }